# Mostrar imagen en listview desde url con Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lista;
ArrayList imagen=new ArrayList();
ArrayList posicion=new ArrayList();
ArrayList hora=new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista=findViewById(R.id.lista);
        descargarImagen();
    }

    private void descargarImagen() {
        imagen.clear();
        posicion.clear();
        hora.clear();

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando datos...");
        progressDialog.show();

        AsyncHttpClient client= new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://192.168.2.19/android/control/jquery.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode==200){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsarray=new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                        for (int i=0;i<jsarray.length();i++){
                            imagen.add(jsarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen"));
                            posicion.add(jsarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posicion"));
                            hora.add(jsarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("hora"));


                        }
                        lista.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }
    private class ImagenAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context ctx;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        ImageView img;
        TextView tposicion,thora;

        public ImagenAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
            this.ctx=applicationContext;
            layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imagen.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return tposicion;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup1=(ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista,null);
            img=(ImageView)viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.img);
            tposicion=(TextView)viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            thora=(TextView)viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

            String urlfinal="http://192.168.2.19/android/control/img/" + imagen.get(i).toString();
            Rect rect = new Rect(img.getLeft(),img.getTop(),img.getRight(),img.getBottom());

            img.setImageurl(urlfinal);
            tposicion.setText(posicion.get(i).toString());
            thora.setText(hora.get(i).toString());
            return viewGroup1;
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy teniendo problemas porque creo que

> img.setimageurl();

está obsoleto ¿alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Agrego 3 opciones para descargar una url de internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de armar un arco de iglesia para descargar la imagen asíncronamente, podrías usar una librería externa que ya hace todo por ti, reduciendo el trabajo a literalmente una sola linea. Te recomiendo [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Debes importar la librería en tu gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(insert latest version)'
```

Aplicándolo a tu código, el getview del adaptador debería quedar algo así:

```
@Override 
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
  ViewGroup viewGroup1 (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista,null);
  img=(ImageView)viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.img);
  tposicion=(TextView)viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
  thora=(TextView)viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

  String urlfinal="http://192.168.2.19/android/control/img/" + imagen.get(i).toString();
  Rect rect = new Rect(img.getLeft(),img.getTop(),img.getRight(),img.getBottom());

  Picasso.with(ctx).load(urlfinal).into(img); //con una línea te descarga asíncronamente la imagen y te la inserta en tu imageview. Awesome =)

  tposicion.setText(posicion.get(i).toString());
  thora.setText(hora.get(i).toString());
  return viewGroup1;
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta , me ha sido de gran utilidad no conocía la libreria picasso, gracias por mostrarmela un saludo

Comment: De nada, recuerda como funciona el sitio. Si te solucionó el problema puntúa positivamente y da la respuesta por válida. Saludos ;)

Comment: soy nuevo , todavia no me deja añadirte un punto positivo , le he clickado al tick y se ha puesto en verde , creo que es eso

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a la carga de las imágenes desde una url puedes usar varias opciones, agrego 3:

- **[GLIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ZzS.png)**

se realiza generalmente es cargar las imágenes desde recursos o desde una url, se agrega la dependencia dentro del archivo `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

esto es un ejemplo:

```
//Obtienes la referencia del ImageView en donde se cagaría la imagen.
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

//Indicas a Glide que imagen cargar y en que vista.
Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://www.midominio.com/myimagen.jpg")
    .into(imageView);
```

Lo interesante de **[Glide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ZzS.png)** es que administra el cache y la memoria requerida para procesar la imagen de una forma optima, además de que es mucho más sencilla su implementación con respecto a `Universal Image Loader`.

- **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**

muy similar a Glide, también incluye administración de caché. Agrega la dependencia dentro del archivo build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

y este es un ejemplo:

```
Picasso.
  with(context).
  load("http://www.midominio.com/myimagen.jpg").
  into(imageView);
```

- **AsynctTask**

#### Como descargar imagen en un ImageView mediante AsynctTask.

Creas un Asynctask donde el proceso de descarga se realiza dentro del método `doInBackground()` :

```
class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public LoadImage(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("LoadImage class", "doInBackground() " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.e("LoadImage class", "Descargando imagen desde url: " + url);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

y llamarías de esta forma el `AsyncTask` para cargar la imagen descargada, definiendo el contenedor `ImageView` y el url de la imagen a descargar:

```
   private ImageView imageView;
   private String imageHttpAddress = "http://jonsegador.com/wp-content/apezz.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        //downloadFile(imageHttpAddress);
        //AsyncTask recibe la referencia del ImageView y la url a descargar.
        new LoadImage(imageView).execute(imageHttpAddress);
    }
```

para obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: odio cuando hacen eso, sobretodo cuando la respuesta está tan currada. Voto positivo =)