# Como cargar una imagen url a otro activity cuando se seleccione un item del spinner en android studio

Tags: android, activity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]por favor, estoy tratando de que se muestre en este acitvity, la imagen url que tengo agregada internamente en el String.xml
quiero saber si hay otra forma de llamar a la imagen a mi ImageView mediante client.get. Gracias

Comment: Mensionas **"Este activity"** pero no pusiste el código, creo que lo olvidaste, modifica tu pregunta proporcionando mas información y porciones de tu código para que podamos entender bien el problema que tienes ;)

Comment: hola israel, podrias ayudarme con este codigo por favor, tengo un ImageView en otro activity, y quiero que se muestre la imagen relacionada al item del spinner que esta en el activity principal.

Comment: Prueba verificando los enlaces que te pongo a continuación: [enlace1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144733/mostrar-imagen-en-listview-desde-url-con-android-studio), [enlace2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: soy nuevo en android, lo que pasa es que las url las tengo en un string array y quiero q se muestre desde la seleccion del item del spinner... me dejo entender?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jonathan, agrega siempre el código como texto, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a el documento [ask], saludos!